# Write a remote txt file using Nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, curl, ftp, raspberry-pi

I am using NodeJs on server-side, but i need to rewrite in a text file(erase it contents and write it again) or to send it to a RaspberryPi in the same network without using ftp, web server or something else in te Raspberry.

I have been reading about `'request'`  for NodeJs but i think i need to have something like a web server installed in the Raspberry to do a `'post'` to certain URL in the Raspberry.

```
   function uploadFile() {
        var formData = {
            // Pass a simple key-value pair
            my_field: 'my_value',
            // Pass data via Buffers
            my_buffer: new Buffer([1, 2, 3]),
            // Pass data via Streams
            my_file: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/unicycle.jpg'),
            // Pass multiple values /w an Array
            attachments: [
                fs.createReadStream(__dirname + 'porton/json.txt')
            ],
            // Pass optional meta-data with an 'options' object with style: {value: DATA, options: OPTIONS}
            // Use case: for some types of streams, you'll need to provide "file"-related information manually.
            // See the `form-data` README for more information about options: https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data
            custom_file: {
                value: fs.createReadStream('/dev/urandom'),
                options: {
                    filename: 'topsecret.jpg',
                    contentType: 'image/jpg'
                }
            }
        };
        request.post({ url: '<RaspberryStaticIP>/route/message.txt', formData: formData }, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error('upload failed:', err);
            }
            console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
        });    
    }
```

https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads

do it with `curl` with MultiPart Upload

```
    curl('127.0.0.1/upload.php', {
    MULTIPART: [
        {name: 'file', file: '/file/path', type: 'text/html'},
        {name: 'sumbit', contents: 'send'}
    ]
}, function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(this.body);
    this.close()
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-curl#multipart-upload

Or, is it possible to do it with `'fs'` but without being local?

```
fs.writeFile('<RaspberryStaticIP>/route/message.txt', '123', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!'); 
});
```

Is there another way to do it only using NodeJs (and any of its implementations) or PHP? In case there isn't possible to do it the way i say, what would be the best, do it via FTP, WebServer in Raspberry or any recomendation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways to put a file on a server, I'm assuming you're doing this on your local network (since you're using an RPi) and don't exactly need to use NodeJS as you hint at PHP etc.  Here is just one of them using a shell script and a Here document:

http://www.stratigery.com/scripting.ftp.html

Comment: I guess this is for Raspberry, but actually i need to send the file from server to Raspberry. Or were you saying that i can install this in Raspberry and get the file remotely?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to login to target server using SSH and then execute your File write command.

Haven't tried this but maybe this could help.

https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2